# Remove Square Brackets and Double quotes from list of strings in Python

Tags: python, list

I need to turn this string that looks like a list into an actual list -

```
status = "[['0', '2', '3', '5']]"
```

and expected result should be

```
status = ['0', '2', '3', '5']
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: _"I need to remove Square brackets and Double quotes from python list"_ -> "I need to turn this string that looks like a list into an actual list"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
import re
status = "[['0', '2', '3', '5']]"
new_status = re.findall('\d+', status)
```

Output:

```
['0', '2', '3', '5']
```

However, you can also use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
new_data = ast.literal_eval(status)[0]
```

Output:

```
['0', '2', '3', '5']
```

Answer (score 3):

The first one is not a list but a string, so you might get along with:

```
from ast import literal_eval
status = "[['0', '2', '3', '5']]"
status = literal_eval(status)
status = status[0]
print(status)
```

This yields

```
['0', '2', '3', '5']
```

But please consider correcting the string in the first place (where does it come from?).